# Passing environment variables in .env file to an Ansible task/playbook

Tags: ansible

I'd appreciate some advice on how to elegantly handle this scenario

- I have an app that requires specific environment variables. The app was built so that I could load a .env file and the app would read in login user/password from environ variables.
- I have a ansible playbook that

  a) Checks out a git repo

  b) Sets up the app
- I need to run the app with the environment variables in place

(These environment variables [as a .env file] are created by a terraform workflow)

What is an elegant way to pass environment variables using a .env file into ansible.builtin.shell/command, etc. without storing them on disk

The .env file is in a key=value format

e.g.

```
USER=Fish
PASSWORD=Net
```

I know that Ansible can read in .yaml/.json files with variables defined, however I want to avoid yet another way of storing login/password parameters.

Comment: You can pass the env variables at runtime of the playbook.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me when trying to read an access token from .env file

1. gets content files as string
2. replaces "TOKEN=" with empty string
3. splits the string at new lines
4. gets the first element in the returned array

```
# app/.env
TOKEN=<token>
USERNAME=<username>

# app/ansible/playbooks/get_token.yml
path: "../../.env"
token: "{{ lookup('file', path) | replace('TOKEN=','') | split('\n') | first }}"



TASK [print token] ******************************************************
ok: [ip] => {
    "msg": [
        "the value of token is <token>"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
- name: Get env vars
  shell: cat .env
  register: env

- name: Run command
  shell: /usr/bin/env {{ env.stdout_lines | join(' ') }} bash -c 'echo $USER $PASSWORD'
  register: echo

- name: debug
  debug:
    var: echo.stdout_lines

TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "echo.stdout_lines": [
        "Fish Net"
    ]
}
```

But I have to say, this was a horrible thing to work out how to do. I was expecting the /usr/bin/env command to take a filename as an argument (like docker does) but no.

Comment: This works when there are no comments or new lines here, other than that, it doesn't work. I think I'm going through the same nightmare you went through Dicky.